# jsonlite working in plain code, but not as a part of a function

Tags: r, jsonlite

I stumbled upon an error:

```
> getBDLsearch("czas")
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

...so I started a teardown to find where the problem is in the function. It's very simple, so I'll just paste it:

```
require(htmltools)
getBDLsearch <- function(query = "", debug = 0, raw = FALSE) {
  url <- paste0('https://api.mojepanstwo.pl/bdl/search?q=', htmlEscape(query))
  if (raw) {
    document <- jsonlite::fromJSON(txt = url,simplifyVector=FALSE)
    return(document)
  } 
  else {
    document <- jsonlite::fromJSON(txt = url,simplifyDataFrame=TRUE)
    return(document)
  }
}
```

( https://github.com/pbiecek/SmarterPoland )

The thing is when I run subsequent lines manually, it works like a charm and the variable "document" gets filled in nicely. I'm curious, why is it so?

Comment: this code works fine for me

Comment: Also as a function? What I mean is that the raw code also works fine for me, but when I call it as a function, it does not.

Comment: it works for me even as a function..

Comment: Now that's strange... What R version do you use?